# Reusing maven configuration

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, profiles

What is the best way to create reusable dependency definitions and profiles in maven?

I would like to externalize dependencies and profiles for integration tests to a separate pom, which can be included in other maven projects (not inheriting from a single parent pom). Later i can activate the profiles when running integration tests on different application servers both from console and eclipse.

```
integrations-tests
    pom.xml (contains Arquillian dependencies and profiles)
        profile:jboss-remote
        profile:tomcat-embedded
        dependencies:Arquillian,Java EE,MavenShrinkWrap etc.
project1
    pom.xml
        dependency:integration-tests (or other way to include)
project2
    module1
        pom.xml
            dependency:integration-tests (or other way to include)

mvn test -P jboss-remote (profile from integrations-tests)
mvn test -P tomcat-embedded (profile from integrations-tests)
```

I don't want to mess with local settings.xml, since the profiles should be reusable by many developers and CI servers.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look at `<dependencyManagement>` and `<pluginManagement>` configurations of maven [pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) to achieve this.  You can look at maven notes on [dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) and [build profiles](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Build+Profiles) (the latter is dated).

You may have a challenge `externalizing` profiles depending on the kind of requirement that you have.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact a good and interesting question.

In short, there is no good way achieving what you want.  What you are looking for is something like Mix-in for sharing configurations, but the main way for sharing configuration in Maven (currently) is mainly by inheritance.

Therefore, the best you can probably do is, to put all those shared config in a parent POM, and turn on/off by use of Profile.  However it may be difficult if you want to turn on in one module but turn off in another.

Mix-in is only available as dependency scope import.  However the use is rather limited (only affect dependencyManagement). You may have a look to see if it can help in part of your requirement.